# ivy ignores ANT_OPTS and -D variables when running from intellij idea

Tags: ant, intellij-idea, ivy

I set environment variable in ANT_OPTS in Windows:

```
-Duser.home=C:/Projects;-Divy.default.ivy.user.dir=C:/Projects/ivy
```

and specified two ant variables in Ant properties window in Intellij Idea

```
user.home C:/Projects
ivy.default.ivy.user.dir C:/Projects/ivy
```

But when I run ant tasks that works with ivy they use my profile home dir (at network dist) as a home dir for ivy repo and all settings are ignored.
In intellij's output I see that it passes

```
-Duser.home=C:/Projects/ -Divy.default.ivy.user.dir=C:/Projects/ivy
```

to ant.

Is it possible to fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: When running your ant task from the command line: is ivy using the values specified in ANT_OPTS ?